# Difficulty accessing contents of JQuery Array

Tags: jquery

I am adding controls to an array in JQuery like this:

```
$('#tblControls tr').each(function () {
var radioButtonText = $(this).find("#td2").find("#chxBxValue").val();
var isSelected = $(this).find("#td2").find("#chxBxSelected");
var $newRdBtn = '';

if (isSelected == 1) {
    $newRdBtn = $('<input />').attr({ id: 'rdBtn', type: 'radio', name: 'rdBtngrp', selected: 'true' }) +'<label for="rdBtn">' + radioButtonText + '</label>';
} else {
    $newRdBtn = $('<input />').attr({ id: 'rdBtn', type: 'radio', name: 'rdBtngrp' }) + '<label for="rdBtn">' + radioButtonText + '</label>';
}

rblArray.push($newRdBtn);
});
```

Later on in another function I try to add the contents of rblArray to a   like so

```
$.each(rblArray, function (intIndex, objValue) {
$("#myPlaceHolder").append(rblArray[intIndex]);
$("#myPlaceHolder").append('<br/>');
 });
```

But this returns

```
[object Object]Test Control 1
[object Object]Test Control 2
```

instead of

```
<input type="radio" name="rdBtngrp" id="rdBtn" />Test Control 1
<input type="radio" name="rdBtngrp" id="rdBtn" />Test Control 2
```

??  What am I missing ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('<input />').attr({ id: 'rdBtn', type: 'radio', name: 'rdBtngrp' })` is an object change it to:

```
if (isSelected == 1) {
    $newRdBtn = '<input id="rdBtn" type="radio" name="rdBtngrp" selected="true" />' +'<label for="rdBtn">' + radioButtonText + '</label>';
} else {
    $newRdBtn = '<input id="rdBtn" type="radio" name="rdBtngrp" />' + '<label for="rdBtn">' + radioButtonText + '</label>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One big problem is ID's must be unique in a page. Change your ID's to classes.

It appears you haven't shown us where the text "Test Control n" is coming from. I suspect you have tried concatenating the text with the existing jQuery object already in your array. An object can't be concatenated with text. If you just push the radios to array as strings instead of wrapping them in "$", should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Error arises from adding a string (with + operator) to jQuery object.

Also, you can accumulate your new elements in a jQuery object instead of an array (not necessary but fun).

Try this:

```
$rbl = $();//empty jQuery object.
$('#tblControls tr').each(function () {
    var $td2 = $(this).find("#td2");//ids must be unique. Try class="td2" and ....find(".td2") instead
    var radioButtonText = $td2.find("#chxBxValue").val();
    var isSelected = $td2.find("#chxBxSelected");//Not sure this is correct?

    var inputProps = { id:'rdBtn', type:'radio', name:'rdBtngrp' };//ids must be unique for label's for="..." to work
    if (isSelected == 1) {
        inputProps.selected = true;
    }

    $span = $('<span></span>');
    $input = $('<input />').attr(inputProps);
    $label = $('<label for="rdBtn">' + radioButtonText + '</label>');//id must match that established above
    $rbl.add($span.append($input).append($label));
});
```

Then, to append them:

```
$rbl.each(function() {
    $("#myPlaceHolder").append(this).append('<br/>');
});
```

As you can see, there's a couple of other things to fix too.